# How to resize a Picture Content Control in VBA

Tags: vba, image, contentcontrol

Is there any way to access the size of a content control.  In a Word document, I've added a Picture Content Control and resized it.  In code, I delete the image and the content control automatically resizes.  Is there way a to set the size in code?  Is there a way to specify the default size of a Picture Content Control so that when there is no image, it uses that size?

contentField.range.InlineShapes.Item(1).Delete

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to set the image and size of a content control image:

```
Private Function insertPicture(tgtDoc As Word.Document, varname As String, file As String, Optional picH As Double = -1)
    Dim tcc As ContentControl, ccList As ContentControls
    Set ccList = tgtDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(varname)
    If ((varname <> "") And (Dir(file) <> "")) Then
        For Each tcc In ccList
            If tcc.Type = wdContentControlPicture Then
                Debug.Print "inserting image from " & file
                Dim picShape As InlineShape
                Set picShape = tgtDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(file, True, True, tcc.Range)
                picShape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                If picH > -1 Then
                    picShape.height = picH
                End If
            End If
        Next tcc
    Else
        Debug.Print "No value set for " & varname
    End If
End Function
```